# HTML Code in Java String without Tags

Tags: java, html, xml, string

I got some HTML in a String named content.

a simple HTML Code:

```
<table>
    <tr role="row">
       <td role="gridcell">Hello</td>
       <td role="gridcell">Another one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
       <td role="gridcell">Second row</td>
       <td role="gridcell">Second column in second row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to build a XML Document with Java.

I got some Methods to add tags, values and attributes:

```
private static Element appendNodeValAttr(Document doc, Node root, String tagName, String value, String... attrs)
    {
        Element e = doc.createElement(tagName);
        if (value != null) {
            e.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < attrs.length; i+=2){
            e.setAttribute(attrs[i], attrs[i+1]);
        }
        root.appendChild(e);

        return e;
    }
```

for example:

```
appendNodeValAttr(doc, html, "font", "Some Text", "size", "30");
```

will return an Element with..

```
<font size="30">Some Text</font>
```

How can I change the String with all the tags, to Elements, which will be added finally to my document?

I really need some help.

Greetings.

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Comment: The expected output is the same like in the String. But I want to build the document with the appendNode Method.

Comment: You can parse the xml string using `DocumentBuilder` and get the document itself. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853541/java-how-to-convert-a-xml-string-into-an-xml-file